# Capturing method in if statement in a list comprehension

Tags: python, list, if-statement, list-comprehension

I have a following use case:

```
[(x, f(x)) for x in list_x if f(x) == cond(x)]
```

Above list comprehension, I think makes a f(x) call twice? How do I avoid that and capture value of f(x) so that f(x) is called only once.

I guess, easy fix is to convert above list comprehension into a for loop, but am curious if it can be done efficiently using a list comprehension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a nested generator expression to call the function only once:

```
[(x, fx) for (x, fx) in ((x, f(x)) for x in list_x) if fx == cond(x)]
```

The generator expression is iterated in lockstep to produce the `(x, fx)` tuples for the list comprehension.

If you find this easier on the reader, you can split out the generator expression into a separate name first:

```
mapped_x = ((x, f(x)) for x in list_x)
filtered_x = [(x, fx) for (x, fx) in mapped_x if fx == cond(x)]
```

To re-iterate this point: the generator expression is executed lazily; the `for` loop in the expression is advanced step by step for each step in the `for ... in mapped_x` loop.

Demo:

```
>>> list_x = range(5)
>>> f = lambda x: print('f({!r})'.format(x)) or (x ** 2 - 1)
>>> cond = lambda x: print('cond({!r})'.format(x)) or x % 2 == 0
>>> mapped_x = ((x, f(x)) for x in list_x)
>>> [(x, fx) for (x, fx) in mapped_x if fx == cond(x)]
f(0)
cond(0)
f(1)
cond(1)
f(2)
cond(2)
f(3)
cond(3)
f(4)
cond(4)
[(1, 0)]
```

Note how `f(x)` is called just once, and the condition is checked immediately.

How efficient this is depends on how costly the `f(x)` call is; a generator expression is executed as a separate function frame, and the interpreter will switch between the two frames (the loop for the list comprehension is also a frame object).

If `f(x)` is a Python function, you'll already have won, as you now halved the number of function frame objects that are created (each `f(x)` call creates a frame object too, and creating these is relatively costly). For C functions, you should create some trial runs with the [`timeit` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) to see what is faster for your expected list size.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to call `f` twice, you can apply `f` to the list first

`[a for a in map(lambda x: (x, f(x)), list_x) if a[1] == cond(x)]`

Comment: Note that using a `lambda` slows this down significantly (creating and popping the function frame object N times for a list length N).

Comment: @MartijnPieters I doubt the qualifier will be  `significantly`. Not that I don't trust you.

Comment: @AnthonyKong: you'd be surprised. Try it out with `timeit`, or check out [Python Function calls are really slow](//stackoverflow.com/a/14648595)

Answer (score 1):

Filter would be a clean way of doing this.  It will evaluate the function passed and if it returns true, it will keep the element, otherwise, no.

```
print (list(filter(lambda x: x[1] == cond(x[0]), [(x, f(x)) for x in list_x])))
```